# Error compiling a test project xamarin form with youtube API

Tags: xamarin.forms, compiler-errors, youtube-data-api

hello i'm debutant with xamarin form and i'm doing a demo app for testing youtube services (recovering videos from a playlist) worry i've got the following i have this error CS0656 C # Member required by the compiler 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder .Binder.Convert 'missing which does not impede compiled the project and I checked the dependencies are well installed ... I followed Tuto for realized this
Forms
Thank you

[This is My SreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/my7OG.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question. If you would include a [mcve], it might be easier for us to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi it's me again I try the project again after a little rest and I realized my work very quickly that I made at the level of data recovery serialize
please see [the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsJ8D.png) for more details

Thank you